# Drupal 7 with Media: YouTube only embeds static image

Tags: media

Using Media (7.x-1.3) and Media: Youtube (7.x-2.0-rc2) to embed a simple YouTube video on a page using the Media Browser in WYSIWYG.  I go to the "Web" tab in the browser, pasted the YouTube URL, and choose the "Default" option.

What gets put into the content is a static image.  What I'm expecting is an embedded video. Even a static image that uses the built-in lightbox capabilities would be fine.

Here's what I've already checked:

- I was getting Lightbox2 errors in admin/config/media/file-types/manage/video/file-display.  Removed Lightbox2 module.
- Went to admin/config/media/file-types/manage/video/file-display and confirmed that **YouTube Video** and **YouTube Preview Image** were selected for the "Default" option.
- Went to admin/config/content/formats/full_html and ensured *Convert Media tags to markup* was enabled.  I also moved it to the top of the order.
- Checked permissions for *View media* in admin/people/permissions

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the latest dev-version of Media:YouTube? I just saw an entry about the same issue here: http://drupal.org/node/1950636.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/70638/10729 but I can't flag it as such because no one voted for the answer there.

Comment: As an unrelated side-note, consider using colorbox instead of lightbox2.

Answer (score 2):

Media 7.x-1.x only embeds images via WYSIWYG.
I would always recommend media 7.x-2.x for anyone unless you have a strict security policy of only using full releases. 2.x has many great new features.

With Media 7.x-2.x:

The media module currently only has support for embedding images via WYSIWYG.

What version of media are you using? If you use media 7.x-2.x you can get it to work by using this sandbox module - http://drupal.org/sandbox/DevinCarlson/1823634 (note that you also need separate http://drupal.org/project/issues/file_entity module with 2.x because it has now been split out of media - it was part of media in 7.x-1.x)

That sandbox module allows configuring which view modes are used for different file types when embedding via WYSIWYG.

There is a related issue for the media module here http://drupal.org/node/1792738 - It has been decided in that issue that the sandbox module will be integrated into the media module. So you can safely use the sandbox knowing that the functionality will eventually be in the media module, at which point you won't need to rely on a sandbox project.

When using that setup of modules I find that in a lot of cases it is also good to use http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode - which allows you to create new view modes (the file_entity 7.x-2.x module doesn't provide many view modes out of the box).

Comment: I am still seeing this issue one year later. Any comments?

Comment: Your best bet for up to date information are the links in the above post. Looks like work is still in progress but there are solutions you can try (patches, sandbox module).